# Fixed Effects Model in SAS

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression

I have 7 independent variables that make up the total score of a company. The 7 independent variables are financial ratios.
When I run my fixed effects regression I get an estimate where standard errors are all zero. I'm assuming a dummy variable trap/ other biases is causing this, but I am extremely new to SAS and want to make sure I am using the absorb/ glm procedure correctly for a fixed effects model. My code is below:

```
proc sort data=MYEXCEL;
   by Company;

proc glm data= MYEXCEL;
   Absorb Company;

model Y = X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 / solution;

store sasuser.Analysis / label='PLM: Getting Started;

run;
```

Comment: Are you able to share any data? And log / lst files?

Comment: What is Y? How are those scores already calculated? If there's a defined formula that relates them that may be way as well.

Comment: Y is the sum of the 7 ratios (X).